# Does 1st Level's Page Table Entry comprised with full paddress?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

I was reading [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lorenzo/corsi/cs372/06F/hw/3sol.html) and at the problem 3, exercise 2 he states:

> The top-level page table should not assume that 2nd level page tables are page-aligned. **So, we store full physical addresses there**. Fortunately, we do not need control bits. So, each entry is at least 44 bits (6 bytes for byte-aligned, 8 bytes for word-aligned). Each top-level page table is therefore 256*6 = 1536 bytes (256 * 8 = 2048 bytes).

So, why does first layer can't assume page aligned 2nd layer?

Since it's presumes that the memory is not allocated in page granularity, wouldn't that make the allocation significantly more complicated?

I have tried btw to read the lectures of the course but they are that comprehensive.

Comment: That sounds like something part of the assignment.

Comment: You are right, the document i linked is supposed to be the solutions